# Why doesn't this code read my file?

Tags: java, exception, file-io

Here is my code to read from a text file:

```
    public RecordManager(){
    int pos;
    String athlete, record, country, raceTime;
    try {
        Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("resultdata.txt"));
        while(scFile.hasNext()){
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(scFile.next()).useDelimiter("#");
            athlete = sc.next();
            country = sc.next();
            pos = sc.nextInt();
            record = sc.next();
            raceTime = sc.next();                
            sc.close();
            if("WRC".equals(record)){
                resultArr[size] = new WorldRecord(athlete, country, pos, raceTime);
            }
            else if("OLR".equals(record)){
                resultArr[size] = new OlympicRecord(athlete, country, pos, raceTime);
            }
            else{
                resultArr[size] = new RaceResult(athlete, country, pos, raceTime);
            }
            size++;
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RecordManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

and here's what's in the text file:

```
Carey Blem#ITA#6#---#4m49.8 
Tammera Hoesly#POR#1#---#4m6.2 
Toi Swauger#FRA#1#OLR#51.3 
Moises Mellenthin#ZIM#2#---#4m34 
Madelene Mcclennon#LUX#1#WRC#1m52.7 
Lashon Meisenheimer#RSA#1#---#2m31.2
```

I have been trying and trying, but I just keep getting this:

```
run:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
at it.practical.training.RecordManager.<init>(RecordManager.java:29)
at it.practical.training.SimpleInterface.main(SimpleInterface.java:20)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 13 seconds)
```

Please tell me what's wrong.

Comment: Why another Scanner sc = new Scanner(scFile.next()).useDelimiter("#"); inside while?

Comment: Perhaps you want to read a full line of scFile rather than just using  `next()`? Still, you can just use one scanner for everything.

Comment: And pos = sc.nextInt(); some of the third tokens in your text file are not int but you are calling sc.nextInt()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `next()` it reads the next word. Your first line has two words `Carey` and `Blem#ITA#6#---#4m49.8`. When you have read words from a line you need to use `nextLine()` to go to the next line.

I suspect what you really want is

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(scFile.nextLine()).useDelimiter("#");
```

To read a whole line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what is wrong but I wouldn't use Scanner to read in a file at all. I would use a [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html), and loop while the readline method does not return null. Then I would use the String class' split method to get the information you need. e.g.

```
public RecordManager(){
  int pos;
  String line;
  String[] info;
  try {
    BufferedReader scFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("resultdata.txt")));
    line = scFile.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        info = line.split("#");//now athlete is in index 0, country at index 1 etc              
        if("WRC".equals(info[3])){
            resultArr[size] = new WorldRecord(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[4]);
        }
        else if("OLR".equals(info[3])){
            resultArr[size] = new OlympicRecord(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[4]);
        }
        else{
            resultArr[size] = new RaceResult(info[0], info[1], info[2], info[4]);
        }
        size++;
        line = scFile.readLine();
     }
  } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(RecordManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  }
}
```

I know it doesn't directly answer what's up with your code but it offers an alternative method of doing what you need. I hope it helps at any rate.